# Set Python SQLAlchemy AutoSchema load_only=True

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Its possible to force AutoSchema use these fields properties? How? Ty.

I know its possible declaring the schema manually.

```
Class TestSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    username = fields.Str(required=True)
    password = fields.Str(required=True, load_only=True)
    ...
```

---

I tried

```
Class TestSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        include_fk = True
        load_instance = True
        include_relationships = False
```

Thank you once again.

I need to AutoSchema use these fields properties!